# Controllers' responsibilities in menu panel

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

I have an application with menu panel (File, Edit, View etc.) and I'm trying to build it using Model View Controller pattern.

Is it a good idea to create one controller for the entire menu, say `MenuController` with methods like `FileSaveAs_clicked`, `EditCopy_clicked` (with assumption that I have another view and controller for main toolbar etc.) or divide controllers responsibility in terms of functionalities (`ClipBoardController`, `FileOperationsController` etc.)? If the second one, then how to divide views' responsibilities?

Maybe someone has any good resources about practical usage of Model View Controller in large applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach this is that I would consider every possible command that is available, regardless of how I present it in the user interface, and then group them based on the level or type of control they will have over the model. My suspicion is that if you merely list every type of command that is possible for the model being viewed, you will find your natural groupings.

I would NOT base my decisions on how they are organized in a menu or toolbar. Whether your system will ever be driven by voice-activation, shell commands, mind control, or whatever... or not, it will benefit in its design if you don't assume that it will always be presented using a traditional desktop GUI.

I might organize them on the nature of the integration with other systems (clipboard, file system, etc.) but I don't like that approach as much.

In other words, my controllers are very much designed around the possible things that I can do to the model with no regard for the view at all, and with as little regard for the underlying integrations as possible.

As a contrived example (since you don't say what your platform or system is about, other than that it seems to be document-based), I might list these commands as being available:

- CopySelectionToClipboard
- CutSelectionToClipboard
- ReplaceSelectionWithClipboardContents
- FormatSelectionUsingClipboardContentsAsTemplate
- CreateNewDocumentFromClipboardContents
- ShowPreviewOfClipboardContents
- GetListOfAvailableClipboardFormats

It doesn't really matter exactly what these are or how they would work, or even that everything has "Clipboard" in the name. None of that gives me a sense of organizational boundary.

Instead, I would look at how each command might interact with the model in context. The first four items are probably directly supported as operations by my document model, but the last two items are very unlikely to be implemented as operations by the document model. Some other part of the model (system model, domain model, etc.) will implement those operations.

So I would probably have three controllers.

1. DocumentSelectionController

   - CopySelectionToClipboard
   - CutSelectionToClipboard
   - ReplaceSelectionWithClipboardContents
   - FormatSelectionUsingClipboardContentsAsTemplate
2. DocumentController

   - CreateNewDocumentFromClipboardContents
3. InformationExchangeController

   - ShowPreviewOfClipboardContents
   - GetListOfAvailableClipboardFormats

This is very rough thinking; I would probably revisit and refine this.

As for the views, I'm not at all sure what you mean by "how to divide views' responsibilities?"

The view has only the responsibility of displaying the model in a particular way and should be entirely independent of the organization of the controllers. The controller has knowledge of the view (it's a "uses" relationship) and what it takes to prepare the view; the view does not have knowledge of the controller.

If a particular view needs to be updated, it can either observe the model itself, or it can be driven by the controller that knows it needs to be updated (or a little of both). In either case, none of the views should change if you were to re-organize the commands in your controllers.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good answer. Especially the very last sentence is worth to keep in mind!
By writing "how to divide views' responsibilities" I meant something like: "how to split the view in classes". Now I have one big class in C# that covers all controls in the application. I feel that this is not a good design. My first idea was to divide it like this: class for menu bar, class for toolbar etc. But how to connect them with controllers?

Comment: You can (usually) nest views within other views. It's fine if you do that based on the actual presentation (button view within a toolbar view within a toolbar group view within a frame view, etc.) Your actual platform will drive how you do that. My responses should apply equally well across all platforms - web, desktops, embedded systems. And your platform will drive how to link the view with the controller. You probably need to ask a new question for that, specific to your platform.

Comment: But, as far as I understand MVC, one controller is handling one view. Therefore, if I follow your answer and create `DocumentSelectionController` and `DocumentController`, shouldn't I keep related GUI controls in `DocumentSelectionView` and `DocumentView` (maybe the names are not good but I wanted to show relations with controllers) or somehow 2 controllers should handle one view?

Comment: If they're nested, the DocumentView contains a DocumentSelectionView (could be a uses-a relationship, not a has-a relationship). The DocumentView has GUI controls that provide a means for gestures (mouse click, keyboard accelerators, voice command..?) to Execute a Command (see Command pattern) that is observed by the DocumentController. The DocumentSelectionView's GUI controls have Commands for the DocumentSelectionController. All of the views are active (visible); all of the associated controllers are ready to observe Command Executions, then update the Model, thus updating the View(s).